# iOS app won't log into Twitter when running on simulator, fixes from other's posts didn't work

Tags: ios, twitter, ios-simulator

I bought a book "Head first iphone and ipad Development" and they provided a simple twitter app to walk through.  When I compile the app and run it on the xCode simulator it doesn't accept my twitter username and password (I made 100% sure the password was correct).

I searched previous posts from people who had the same or similar issue and this led me to change the target deployment in my build settings to 6.1, but it didn't fix the problem. I noticed that my project (the tree in the upper left hand corner) still said 7.0 even after confirming it accepted the new deployment target in the build settings.  Is there something I need to do in the simulator to choose 6.1 instead of 7.0 beyond the build settings?  Also from a high level, can anyone explain why a bug like this would exist? Is it a bug in xCode and another IDE would be better? Is the package social.package included in my project out of date and I should just update that?  I was a visual basic programmer and now trying to port my skills onto the wide world of iOS dev.  The ultimate app I plan to build will involve facebook and twitter extensively so I want to get a handle on what is going on here.

-dan

Comment: The best way to test FB and Twitter integration is on the device. I never had too much luck on the Simulator.

Comment: I haven't paid the $100 to test on a real device yet. Is there really nothing I can do to figure out why the simulator isn't working? I see other posts where people apparently have been able to get it working. Is there anywhere I can go to pay someone to help me figure this kind of stuff out? I am not getting very much from this post

Comment: Can you post your code on how you are doing integration. Are you using the built in social media add in or are you doing it in code only. There should be a twitter login. Normally you go into settings and setup twitter and fb with your logins. It should never ask you.

Comment: ill look at it tonight after work and see if I can do it through the simulator.

Comment: I am using the built in social.package

Comment: When I kick off the simulator I go into the simulated iPhones settings just as if it was an iphone and enter in my twitter/fb credentials.  When I do that in the simulators "settings" I get wrong u/p even though I know the values are correct.  I doubt it has anything to do with the actual app (though happy to share whatever about the app may assist) since the failure is outside the app's "settings" area.  My app doesn't have the chance to fail because the simulator won't accept my twitter/FB credentials.

Comment: I have never been able to get Twitter/FB integration working on the Simulator. I always put it on a device

Answer (score 0):

For twitter integration you can use this.

https://github.com/fhsjaagshs/FHSTwitterEngine

may be it will help you.

Comment: I tried the FHSTwitter Engine and it has the same issue where when I try to log into my twitter account through the simulator it says username and password are wrong even though they are correct.  Not sure where to go from here

Comment: I haven't paid the $100 to test on a real device yet.  Is there really nothing I can do to figure out why the simulator isn't working?  I see other posts where people apparently have been able to get it working.  Is there anywhere I can go to pay someone to help me figure this kind of stuff out?  I am not getting very much from this post.